# Where can I find the polygon.curve.fi interfaces for solidity?

Tags: solidity, python, polygon

I am trying to interact with the aave curve pool. I have the interface for the curve polygon pools, but they are written in vyper not solidity.

https://github.com/curvefi/curve-contract-polygon/blob/master/contracts/pools/aave/StableSwapAave.vy

For example:

```
    def add_liquidity(_amounts: uint256[N_COINS], _min_mint_amount: uint256, _use_underlying: bool = False) -> uint256:   
@notice Deposit coins into the pool
    @param _amounts List of amounts of coins to deposit
    @param _min_mint_amount Minimum amount of LP tokens to mint from the deposit
    @param _use_underlying If True, deposit underlying assets instead of aTokens
    @return Amount of LP tokens received by depositing
```

How do I interact with this contract in solidity? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

here is a collection of the all interfaces related to curve on polygon : https://github.com/curvefi/curve-contract-polygon/tree/master/interfaces

Alternatively, you can visit polygonscan on a specific contract address and copy ABI from there.

You can also install the vyper compiler locally and then compile a specific contract to get abi output, command would look something like this:

```
vyper -f abi  contract.vy > contract.json
```

Comment: How do I use the ABI in solidity? For example, the function I put in the question.